# Getting conflict while using 'rpush' gem and 'rpush-mongoid' gem with the Mongoid version in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Can anyone tell me which is the best gem to send notification messages to Android Device?

Answer (score 1):

You can check [gcm](https://github.com/spacialdb/gcm) and [pushmeup](https://github.com/NicosKaralis/pushmeup) gem. These might be useful.